# Многоуровневая выборка

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть таблица category, её структура примерно такова

```
category_id    parent_id
```

Соответственно у каждой категории есть родительская категория (если нет то 0). Необходимо зная category_id узнать всех родителей. Например таблица заполнена след образом

```
category_id     parent_id
1               0
2               0   
3               0
4               1
5               4
6               5
```

Нам необходимо узнать всех родителей категории с id=6 (т.е. 5,4,1,0).
можно конечно сначала сделать

```
select * from table where category_id=6
```

Затем по одному вытаскивать её родителей. Но надо сделать все это в один запрос. Вариант:

```
select parent_id from table where  category_id=(select parent_id from table where  category_id=6)
```

Тоже не подходит, так как нам заведома не известна глубина категории (с id=6)
Буду благодарен за помощь.

upd

На примере. Есть следующая иерархия категорий

level0 (id=0)->level1 (id=1)->level2 (id=4)->level3 (id=5)-> categoty_id-6

Так вот надо узнать всех родителей категории с id=6 (последняя) т.е. 5,4,1,0. Нам дан только этот id категории

Comment: Не уверен что понял ход Ваших мыслей, но посмотрите [это][1].

[1]: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: А известен максимально возможный уровень вложенности?

Comment: @AppLend  нет

Answer (score 1):

Сделать это в один запрос вряд ли получиться незная глубины вложенности.

Как вариант можно добавить столбец path (если вам можно модифицировать таблицу), который будет содержать путь до текущей категории. Например в вашем пример для категории с category_id = 6, path будет таким 5-4-1, для 5 это 4-1, для 4 это 1

В таком случае запрос может быть таким:

```
SELECT * FROM cats WHERE FIND_IN_SET(category_id, (SELECT REPLACE(path, '-', ',') FROM cats WHERE category_id = 6));
```

Еще вариант можно написать хранимую функцию.

Answer (score 0):

При максимальном уровне вложенности в таблице 5 такой запрос:

```
select t.parent_id, lev1.parent_id, lev2.parent_id, lev3.parent_id, lev4.parent_id
from  category t
left join category lev1 on (lev1.category_id = t.parent_id)
left join category lev2 on (lev2.category_id = lev1.parent_id)
left join category lev3 on (lev3.category_id = lev2.parent_id)
left join category lev4 on (lev4.category_id = lev3.parent_id)
where t.category_id = 6;
```

Результат будет:       5   4   1   0   null